# Swiperjs in React : swiper.slideTo TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swiper.js

I am trying to use Swiperjs in my project, in a Typescript file. I want to change the active slide from another component (Tabs, from material UI, already in place). I can swipe directly in the Swiper component but I'd like to make that possible otherwise and elsewhere as well.

However I do not find the way to trigger the method `slideTo` ([here](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#methods-and-properties) the API) outside the component

```
...
<Swiper
   onSlideChange={(swiper) => setValue(swiper.realIndex)}
   ...
> 
Here my slides, other components, ...
</Swiper>
```

So ideally I'd rather like to have something like :

```
...

function handleExternalChangeSlide=(newSlideIndexToShow)=>{
   swiper.slidesTo(newSlideIndexToShow)
}

<Swiper
   onSlideChange={(swiper) => setValue(swiper.realIndex)}
   ...
> 
Here my slides, other components, ...
</Swiper>
```

I have seen many people doing that:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  ... options
});

function handleExternalChangeSlide=(newSlideIndexToShow)=>{
   swiper.slidesTo(newSlideIndexToShow)
}
)
```

But actually, Typescript claims that: *Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword* and I do not know how to handle that

Do you see any way to proceed to be able to change the active slide (without using pagination from Swiper) outside Swiper component in my .tsx file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Swiper` component takes `onSwiper` props a function that will return you an instance of the created Swiper.
You can save this instance to a `state` and then call all the methods you need on it.

Here is one of the implementation options:

```
const [swiperInstance, setSwiperInstance] = useState<SwiperCore>();

const handleExternalChangeSlide = (newSlideIndexToShow) => {
   swiperInstance.slidesTo(newSlideIndexToShow);
}

...
<Swiper
   onSwiper={setSwiperInstance}
   onSlideChange={(swiper) => setValue(swiper.realIndex)}
   ...
> 
Here my slides, other components, ...
</Swiper>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is actually so easy. Thank you for your precious and fast help!

Comment: This is the bit I was missing: `useState<SwiperCore>()`

Comment: Where to import SwiperCore from? As I checked, it's not exported from 'swiper/types'

Comment: I found it:
import SwiperCore from 'swiper';

Answer (score 1):

you can also manage navigation in swiperjs with useRef if you're using reactjs

```
  const swiperRef = useRef<SwiperRef>(null);
  const clickNext = () => {
    swiperRef.current?.swiper?.slideNext();
  };

  return(
   <div>
    <button onClick={clickNext}>go Next </button>

     <Swiper
      ref={swiperRef}
      slidesPerView={"auto"}
      centeredSlides={true}
      spaceBetween={30}
      className="featured-carousel"
      modules={[Navigation]}
    >
      {carouselList?.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <SwiperSlide key={index}>
              slide {index}
            </SwiperSlide>
        );
      })}
    </Swiper>
   </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a ref for the `swiper` react component like this:

```
const swiperRef = useRef<SwiperRef>(null);

<Swiper ref={swiperRef}
```

And then access `swiper` functions like `slideNext` `slidePrev` from it:

```
const slideNext = (): void => swiperRef?.current?.swiper.slideNext();

const slidePrev = (): void => swiperRef?.current?.swiper.slidePrev();
```